# dosbox masm input along with debug

Tags: debugging, input, masm, dosbox

I'm using DOSBox MASM to learn Assembly Language. However, I want to give input along with debug. That is, I want to execute my program line by line and also give input as soon as

```
INT 21H
```

comes. I'm debugging in

```
afdebug test.exe
```

But as soon as it sees

```
MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
```

The debug just skips after INT 21H and doesn't prompt any screen to take input.

Here is the program in case:

```
.MODEL SMALL
        .STACK 64
        .DATA
MSG DB "ENTER A CHARACTER:$"
ORG 0030H
LOL DB ?
        .CODE
            MOV AX,@DATA
            MOV DS,AX
            LEA DX,MSG
            MOV AH,09H
            INT 21H
            MOV AH,01H
            INT 21H
            MOV LOL,AL
            MOV AH,4CH
            INT 21H
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I come across the question some days ago, I solved it finally. and I debug my code use instruction `t`

> Executes one instruction and then displays the contents of all registers, the status of all flags, and the decoded form of the instruction that Debug will execute next.

in DosBox,  and I found after `INT 21H`, the next instruction is `STI`, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_flag#STI)

> The STI instruction enables interrupts by setting the IF.

so after the instruction `STI`, you can take input.

You can visit other detail in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc722863(v=technet.10) to learn more about debug instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by following method 
i think interrupt flag is reset in the debug mode so calling int 21h is doing nothing.
*"If interrupt flag is reset (0), the microprocessor will not recognize any interrupt requests and will ignore them."*

what i tried was i changed my code and included `STI` before calling any interrupts.(STI stands for Set Interrupt Flag)
Now when i run application in debug mode i am able to give input